# How to get friends in order of number of mutual friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-apps

I am developing a Facebook application. I want to know how I can get friends in the order of number of mutual friends.
Is it possible with FQL or any other method?

Answer (score 6):

### Update

I can't find a way to do it in one request using graph API 
but it can be done in Ruby by getting friends list then sending request for each friend using [User context](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-context/all_mutual_friends/) like [this example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=520370946%3Ffields%3Dcontext.fields%2528mutual_friends%2529&)

### Original answer

Here is the FQL query to be used **Which is working only for api versions < v2.1**

```
SELECT uid, mutual_friend_count from user where uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) ORDER BY mutual_friend_count desc
```

you can try it in the explorer

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20uid%2C%20mutual_friend_count%2C%20friend_count%20from%20user%20where%20uid%20in%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%3Dme%28%29%29%20ORDER%20BY%20mutual_friend_count%20desc

Comment: For other noobs: I needed to switch from `Graph API` to `FQL Query` for this to work in the explorer. Otherwise I received a `"(#601) Parser error: unexpected end of query."` error. :)

Comment: I think the API has changed. This query now returns
`{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#12) fql is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 12
  }
}`

Comment: The explorer doesn't seem to show all of my friends. Why not?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, you can get a list of a user's friends using:

```
$friendsOfFriend = $facebook->api('/'.$yourFriendsFacebookId.'/friends');
```

Then you can check each of the result to see if they are your friend too.

```
$isMyFriend = $facebook->api('/me/friends/'.$someonesFacebookId);
```

... and keep a track of the count.

However my test didn't return any result yet. I attempted to get the friends of some of my facebook friends but it returns an exception: `Can't lookup all friends of {friend's_facebook_ID}. Can only lookup for the logged in user {my_facebook_ID}, or friends of the logged in user with the appropriate permission`. So there might be permission issue here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think mutual friends are available via FQL so you would have to do this the hard:  calling the graph api in a loop for each friend and getting a count of mutual friends.  The graph api method is: /me/mutualfriends/yourFriendsId and you could do 20 batch requests at a time to help speed this up.  If you can find a way to do this with FQL, that would be your fastest route.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer as they are not all in one place, still haven't found a way to get them on one page yet, but it is a start, could be run in a loop programmatically through your friend list...

```
https://www.facebook.com/browse/mutual_friends/?uid=xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

because if you don't give a uid it returns an error... I was just trying to get a list of all my friends on one pagem, but no dice. ridonculous.